# What is the difference between ActionErrors and ActionMessages struts 1.3

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I have been using struts-errors to pass messages from dispatch action class to view page
But I found out struts-messages is standard tag to do this
First what is difference between these two classes
Secondly how to use struts-errors , i tried follwing code but it did not worked

```
        messages.add("PreferencesUpdated",new ActionMessage("Your preferences has been updated"));
        saveMessages(request, messages);
        request.setAttribute("messages", true);
        return mapping.findForward(subscribe);
```

and in the view page

```
<span style="font-weight:bold"><html:messages id="PreferencesUpdated" message="true" /></span>
```

Can anyone tell where is error in the code and difference between   and

Comment: I think there is not much difference between the two because `Action Error` has been deprecated in favour of `Action Message`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **NO** any difference ,`ActionErrors` are deprecated.  all behavior in `ActionErrors` was pushed up into `ActionMessages` . This was done in the attempt to clearly signal that these classes can be used to pass any kind of messages from the controller to the view -- errors being only one kind of message.

Main advantage of `ActionMmessage` tag is it does not force to write html tags in properties file but `ActionError` object forces to write html tags.